# Sorting numeric column in datagridview

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I am using a datagridview to show data in csv file. One of the column in datagridview in of numeric type [Column name: ID].

I am using autosort method of datagridview(sorting by clicking column header).
This works well for all the columns except this numeric column.
This column contains numbers 1 to 55

What I am getting now is after sorting is:

```
1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,3,30,31...
```

...and so on. what I want is:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,...
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The column 'ID' is stored as a String. That's why it's sorted 1, 10, 11 ,...
Can you post some code ?

Comment: private void btnSort_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in Grid.Columns)
            {
                Grid.Columns[column.Name].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
            }
        }

Comment: Look at the answer from @lem2802, I think it is exactly what you are searching for. The problem is, if you read a csv-file all the values are Strings. DataGridview just sorts Strings by their charactervalue.

Comment: Can anybody comment about how to get data from csv to datagridview so that this kind of sorting can be done?

Comment: Yes, you can create a container (a DataTable for instance) and use this container as DataSource. Before storing the IDs in the DataTable you have to convert it to an Integer. I can post some code as answer if you want.

Comment: yes, please :) I am waiting

Comment: @killexe I have also added 'Grid.Columns[0].ValueType = typeof(int);' to avoid string sorting problem. but of no use!

Comment: Do you set the type before you add your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("ForeName");
```

I am using these columns due to the fact that I don't know what data you are storing.

After reading your csv-file you have to iterate through the data. Considering you have your data stored in a String array (String[][] arr) with the inner ArrayLength of 3 (ID, Name, ForeName).

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["ID"] = Convert.ToInt32(arr[i][0]);
    row["Name"] = arr[i][1];
    row["ForeName"] = arr[i][2];
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

I hope this helps, it's a sample Code.

The reference to DataTable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx

**EDIT**

I just read that you already have a DataTable as result. You can build another DataTable as I did and iterate through your Data and convert the ID to an Integer. Please don't forget to set the Columns Type:

```
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the event `SortCompare` like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e) {
    //Suppose your interested column has index 1
    if (e.Column.Index == 1){
       e.SortResult = int.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()).CompareTo(int.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()));
       e.Handled = true;//pass by the default sorting
     }
}
```

Comment: Tried! Code for this event is unreachable ! Donno why? :(

Comment: @MrAj did you add the event to the DataGridView? For example: `dvg.OnSortCompare += dataGridView1_SortCompare;`
`dvg` is the DataGridView.

Comment: Where should i add this event? OnFormLoad ? Previously, I added this event by clicking in grid->properties->events->setcompare. Is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your column is not numeric, but a text column that contains *numeric string values*. There's a huge difference! A real numeric column would apply numeric sorting, while your column uses alphanumeric sorting.

I'd try to actually change the underlying data type to `int` instead of `string` or apply manual sorting as suggested by `lem2802`.

Please add some information about how you fill the data grid view. Maybe that can help find an easier way than implementing a manual sort comparison.

---

According to your comment you create a `DataTable` as the data source for the grid view. You need to make sure that the column(s) containing numeric values also have a numeric type. In the code where you create the table and its columns, do something like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
... // Other columns
```

Later when you create the rows based on the content of your CSV file, make sure to fill each row so that the value for the ID column actually is an `int`:

```
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row["ID"] = Convert.ToInt32(idValueFromCSV);
... // Other columns
```

That way you'll get what you want without implementing custom sorting.

Comment: I am using                                                                                            private DataTable loadCSVDataTable(string strCsvFilePath)
        {                    using TextFieldparser i am returning datatable      }

Comment: And then   Grid.DataSource = dtAllTableData.DefaultView;

Comment: Then you should change the definition of your `DataTable` (the part where you create the columns) to create an `Int32` column. I'll edit my answer to show you an example.